# Get child element from event.target

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

`event.target` returns the DOM element an action was performed on. How do I get a specific child element from the output?

Here's my form (with Angular markup):

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)" id="kekpek">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Example file input</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" #fileupload [(ngModel)]="myFile" name="myFile" (change)="fileChange($event)"/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It fires the function:

```
onSubmit(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

Which output the entire form. I need to access the `input` element in the `onSubmit()` function.

Comment: How do you identify this specific child element? As it stands, we don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: You can use `event.target.children` to get a list of children (if that wasn't obvious)!

Comment: you can use the query api on the element

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the `documentElement.querySelector()` method.

```
function onSubmit(event){
    console.log(event.target.querySelector('input'));

}
```

You can use any valid CSS query to get the element you need

Comment: And `event.target.querySelector('input').value` will give you the content of input

Comment: It also doesn't get an element's children like the question asked.

Comment: @BenRacicot The text of the question says `How do I get a specific child element from the output?` which is what the answer above tries to solve. If you want all the children, you can just use [ParentNode.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)

Answer (score 3):

This should help

```
onSubmit(event) {
    console.log(event.target.firstChild.children[1]);
}
```

Comment: Also if it is needed on 1st nested level the last one to catch, then with `event.target.lastChild`.